# Error message translate incorrect with data-val-number asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unobtrusive-validation

I use Entity Framework and use `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to validation for entity object on screen.

When `CurrentThread` is **English** error message of `data-val-number` is correct.

> *Message:* The field IntKey must be a number.

When `CurrentThread` is **Japan** error message of `data-val-number` is incorrect.

> *Message:* !FUV5H!The field IntKey must be a number. 表©鷗字!

Other error message when `CurrentThread` **japan** are correct

```
<input class="form-control" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-number="!FUV5H!The field IntKey must be a number. 表©鷗字!" 
       data-val-required="IntKey フィールドが必要です。" id="IntKey" 
       name="IntKey" 
       type="text" 
       value="" >
```

How solution for this case.

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem (you are saying everything is correct)?

Comment: Seems that you want to use localized jQuery validation, I suggest you to use resource file with strongly-typed viewmodel properties instead of manually configuring `data-val-` attribute (by using data annotation attribute utilizing `ErrorMessageResourceType` & `ErrorMessageResourceName`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Error message expect: "The field IntKey must be a number". But, actual message:  "!FUV5H!The field IntKey must be a number. 表©鷗字!"

Comment: @TetsuyaYamaoto thanks you, i know but this is default error message of Jquery.validation when validation input must be number